How to make this type of card component
I am just wondering what are a component to make a Ui design card.cause I saw a lot of these cool card design on pinterest and I was wondering how to make it. Like what are the component to make such a design with SwiftUI

i have tried it ! the further i have extended the image is this


import SwiftUI
struct RoundedCorners: Shape {
    var radius: CGFloat = 25.0
    var corners: UIRectCorner = .allCorners
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath(
            roundedRect: rect,
            byRoundingCorners: corners,
            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius)
        )
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("images")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200) // Set your desired image size
            .clipShape(RoundedCorners(radius: 50, corners: [.topLeft, .bottomRight]))
            .shadow(radius: 5)
            .padding()
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


i have tried this but can't .If anyone knows how to make this with a standard.

I don't know why this question was closed, it's a very valid question for beginners. For your second example, you can simply do .clipShape(UnevenRoundedRectangle(topLeadingRadius: 50, bottomTrailingRadius: 50)) to achieve the same result without needing to make a custom Shape. Just FYI.

The basic shape can be built by creating a path and adding arcs to it.

One approach is to create a custom Shape, as you were doing originally. However, doing it this way, it will be difficult to reserve the correct amount of space for showing the label in the top-left corner, unless the size of the label is fixed of course.

If you want to show a label that can contain text of varying size and also adapt to dynamic font sizes, then an alternative approach is to use a Canvas. You can then pass in the label as a "symbol" for the canvas to use.

A Canvas receives a GraphicsContext as parameter and this lets you measure the size of images and other symbols. So this makes it possible to build a path that fits exactly to the size of the label.

An easy way to draw the curves is to use addArc(tangent1End:tangent2End:radius:transform:). Here you just pass in the points that you would use if you were drawing the shape with square corners, instead of rounded corners.


For the round button bottom-right, it is not possible to attach a tap gesture to a symbol that is passed to the Canvas. Here is what the documentation says on this point:

The symbol inputs, like all other elements that you draw to the canvas, lack individual accessibility and interactivity, even if the original SwiftUI view has these attributes.

However, the size of this button is probably fixed, so the path can just be built using this fixed size (instead of passing the button as a symbol). Then the button itself can be shown as an overlay over the canvas, using alignment .bottomTrailing.
Here is an example to show it working this way:
struct CardWithInsetCorners: View {
    let label: String
    let image: Image
    let roundButtonDiameter: CGFloat = 44
    let roundedCornerRadius: CGFloat = 10
    let gapToCornerItems: CGFloat = 4

    var body: some View {
        Canvas { ctx, size in
            if let label = ctx.resolveSymbol(id: "label") {

                // Draw the label in the top-left corner
                ctx.draw(label, in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: label.size))

                // Build a path with rounded corners
                let path = pathWithRoundedCorners(canvasSize: size, labelSize: label.size)

                // Use the path as clip shape for subsequent drawing operations
                ctx.clip(to: path)
            }
            // Determine the rectangle for the image when scaled to fill
            let resolvedImage = ctx.resolve(image)
            let rect = rectForImage(canvasSize: size, imageSize: resolvedImage.size)

            // Show the image
            ctx.draw(resolvedImage, in: rect)

        } symbols: {
            labelInCorner.tag("label")
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
            roundButton
        }
    }

    private func pathWithRoundedCorners(canvasSize: CGSize, labelSize: CGSize) -> Path {
        let wLabel = labelSize.width + gapToCornerItems
        let hLabel = labelSize.height + gapToCornerItems
        let wButton = roundButtonDiameter + gapToCornerItems
        let hButton = roundButtonDiameter + gapToCornerItems
        return Path { path in

            // Begin half-way down the left side
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: canvasSize.height / 2))

            // Rounded-corner bottom-left of label
            path.addArc(
                tangent1End: CGPoint(x: 0, y: hLabel),
                tangent2End: CGPoint(x: wLabel, y: hLabel),
                radius: roundedCornerRadius
            )
            // Rounded-corner bottom-right of label
            path.addArc(
                tangent1End: CGPoint(x: wLabel, y: hLabel),
                tangent2End: CGPoint(x: wLabel, y: 0),
                radius: (hLabel + gapToCornerItems) / 2
            )
            // Rounded-corner top-right of label
            path.addArc(
                tangent1End: CGPoint(x: wLabel, y: 0),
                tangent2End: CGPoint(x: canvasSize.width, y: 0),
                radius: roundedCornerRadius
            )
            // Rounded-corner top-right
            path.addArc(
                tangent1End: CGPoint(x: canvasSize.width, y: 0),
                tangent2End: CGPoint(x: canvasSize.width, y: canvasSize.height - hButton),
                radius: roundedCornerRadius
            )
            // Rounded-corner top-right of round button
            path.addArc(
                tangent1End: CGPoint(x: canvasSize.width, y: canvasSize.height - hButton),
                tangent2End: CGPoint(x: canvasSize.width - wButton, y: canvasSize.height - hButton),
                radius: roundedCornerRadius
            )
            // Rounded-corner top-left of round button
            path.addArc(
                tangent1End: CGPoint(x: canvasSize.width - wButton, y: canvasSize.height - hButton),
                tangent2End: CGPoint(x: canvasSize.width - wButton, y: canvasSize.height),
                radius: (wButton + gapToCornerItems) / 2
            )
            // Rounded-corner bottom-left of round button
            path.addArc(
                tangent1End: CGPoint(x: canvasSize.width - wButton, y: canvasSize.height),
                tangent2End: CGPoint(x: 0, y: canvasSize.height),
                radius: roundedCornerRadius
            )
            // Rounded-corner bottom-left
            path.addArc(
                tangent1End: CGPoint(x: 0, y: canvasSize.height),
                tangent2End: CGPoint(x: 0, y: canvasSize.height / 2),
                radius: roundedCornerRadius
            )
            path.closeSubpath()
        }
    }

    private func rectForImage(canvasSize: CGSize, imageSize: CGSize) -> CGRect {
        let wImage = imageSize.width
        let hImage = imageSize.height
        let scalingFactor = max(canvasSize.width / wImage, canvasSize.height / hImage)
        let w = wImage * scalingFactor
        let h = hImage * scalingFactor
        let xImage = (canvasSize.width - w) / 2
        let yImage = (canvasSize.height - h) / 2
        return CGRect(
            origin: CGPoint(x: xImage, y: yImage),
            size: CGSize(width: w, height: h)
        )
    }

    private var labelInCorner: some View {
        Text(label)
            .font(.subheadline)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            .padding(.vertical, 6)
            .background {
                Capsule()
                    .fill(Color(.systemGray5))
            }
    }

    private var roundButton: some View {
        Image(systemName: "heart")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .padding(12)
            .frame(width: roundButtonDiameter, height: roundButtonDiameter)
            .background {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color(.systemGray5))
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                print("+like")
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CardWithInsetCorners(
            label: "Music",
            image: Image(.image3)
        )
        .frame(height: 350)
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
    }
}



Thanks @benzy-neez for the helpful answer! As a beginner, I'm eager to learn more about SwiftUI and iOS development. Can you recommend any resources (tutorials, courses, books, etc.) for learning these topics?

@BlurryFace Pleased to have been able to help, thanks for accepting the answer. Re. resources, I guess the Apple tutorials would be a good place to start: Introducing SwiftUI

As an alternative to the accepted answer, here's another way to go about it.
Possibly because of my creative background, I thought this could be achieved using a shape to basically mask/stamp out the corners where needed. I got a little carried away in the process, but I think I ended up with something very flexible.
The key to this method is a simple round corner shape - basically an arc with a custom radius:


Example 1 - Simple shape
Using various blend modes, this shape can be used to either mask out a corner or fill a corner:

This is done through an .overlay modifier that:

Aligns one corner shape to the top left
Aligns another corner shape with a larger radius to the top right, rotates it 180 degrees, and flips it vertically.



Example 2 - Advanced shape
By combining corners with different radius values and placement, many shapes can be achieved:

Note: The code for the above example is included below. See preview named "RoundCorner Test"

Reproducing the artist card
Using this method, we can apply it to an overlay text in a capsule aligned to the top left, to add and mask out corners as needed.
ArtistCard(image: "halsey")
    .overlay(alignment: .topLeading) {
        Text("Music")
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            .padding(.vertical, 5)
            .background(.white.opacity(0.9), in: Capsule())
            .padding(10)
        }


Then mask out the background behind the text capsule and fill in the bottom right corner:
.roundCorners(.fill) { 
    RoundCorner(radius: 20, alignment: .bottomTrailing, orientation: .bottomTrailing, position: .inside, flip: .trailing)
}


Add two more corners, to the bottom left and the top right, on the outside:
.roundCorners { // (.mask) is implied as parameter - to mask out parts of the card
    RoundCorner(radius: 20, alignment: .bottomLeading, orientation: .topLeading, position: .outside, flip: .bottom)
    RoundCorner(radius: 20, alignment: .topTrailing, orientation: .topLeading, position: .outside, flip: .trailing)
                        }


Similarly, another label with the artist name can be added to the bottom right of the card, for the final result:

Because it is just overlaying views, the content can be anything, including a button:

Note that this method also allows for transparency, so that you don't have to joggle the overlay colors to match the background color.

To recap:

Automatically adapts to content shape and size
Easily animatable (see demo)
Each corner can have its own radius value
Allows for use of buttons or any view really
Allows for background colors to come through

The working code below includes some controls to play around with:


Code:
import SwiftUI


//MARK: - Main view

struct CustomArtistCard: View {
    
    //State values
    @State private var artistName: String = "Artist"
    @State private var isLiked: Bool = false

    //Form states
    @State private var selectedElement: ElementType = .rect
    @State private var backgroundHue: Double = 0.5
    @State private var elementSize: Double = 1.0
    
    //Computed properties
    private var currentColor: Color {
        Color(hue: backgroundHue, saturation: 0.5, brightness: 0.9)
    }
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            
            Spacer()
            
            ArtistCard(image: "") // <- Specify your named image from Assets here
            
                //MARK: - Top left
            
                .overlay(alignment: .topLeading) {
                    Text("Music")
                        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                        .padding(.vertical, 5)
                        .background(.white, in: Capsule())
                        .padding(10)
                        .roundCorners(.fill) {
                            RoundCorner(radius: 20, alignment: .bottomTrailing, orientation: .bottomTrailing, position: .inside, flip: .trailing)
                        }
                        .roundCorners {
                            RoundCorner(radius: 20, alignment: .bottomLeading, orientation: .topLeading, position: .outside, flip: .bottom)
                            RoundCorner(radius: 20, alignment: .topTrailing, orientation: .topLeading, position: .outside, flip: .trailing)
                        }
                }
            
                //MARK: - Bottom right
                
                .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                    
                    Group {
                        
                        //MARK: - Singer name
                        
                        if selectedElement == .rect {
                            
                            if artistName != "" {
                                Text(artistName)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                                    .background(.gray.opacity(0.2), in: Capsule())
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                                    .background(.white, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
                                    .padding(10)
                            }
                            else {
                                EmptyView()
                            }
                        }
                        
                        //MARK: - Like button
                        
                        else {
                            
                            //Like button
                            Button {
                                isLiked.toggle()
                            } label: {
                                withAnimation(.interactiveSpring) {
                                    Image(systemName: isLiked ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                                }
                            }
                            .tint(isLiked ? .red : .gray)
                            .padding(10)
                            .background(.white.opacity(0.7), in: Circle())
                            .padding(5)
                        }
                    }
                    .roundCorners(.fill) {
                        RoundCorner(radius: 20, alignment: .topLeading, orientation: .topLeading, position: .inside)

                    }
                    .roundCorners {
                        RoundCorner(radius: 20, alignment: .bottomLeading, orientation: .bottomTrailing, position: .outside, flip: .leading)
                        RoundCorner(radius: 20, alignment: .topTrailing, orientation: .bottomTrailing, position: .outside, flip: .top)
                    }
                    .scaleEffect(elementSize, anchor: .bottomTrailing)
                    
                }
                .compositingGroup()
                .animation(.easeInOut, value: selectedElement)
                .animation(.default, value: artistName)
            
            
            //MARK: - Demo Controls
            
            Form {
                
                Section("Element type") {
                    Picker("Element", selection: $selectedElement) {
                        Text("Rectangle").tag(.rect as ElementType)
                        Text("Circle").tag(.circle as ElementType)
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                }
                
                if selectedElement == .rect {
                    Section {
                        TextField("Change text...", text: $artistName)
                    } header: {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Change name")
                            Spacer()
                            Button {
                                withAnimation {
                                    artistName = ""
                                }
                            } label: {
                                Text("Clear")
                                    .font(.caption2)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(.plain)
                        }
                    }
                    .transition(.blurReplace)
                }
                
                //MARK: - Slider - Background color
                
                Section {
                    HStack {
                        Slider(value: $backgroundHue, in: 0...1) {
                            Text("Background color")
                        }
                    }
                } header: {
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text("Background color")
                        Spacer()
                        
                        //Reset button
                        if backgroundHue != 0.5 {
                            Button {
                                withAnimation {
                                    backgroundHue = 0.5
                                }
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: "gobackward")
                                    .imageScale(.small)
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(.plain)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                //MARK: - Slider - Element size
                
                Section {
                    Slider(value: $elementSize, in: 0.5...2) {
                        Text("Background color")
                    }
                } header: {
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text("Element size")
                        Spacer()
                        
                        //Reset button
                        if elementSize != 1.0 {
                            Button {
                                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                                    elementSize = 1.0
                                }
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: "gobackward")
                                    .imageScale(.small)
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(.plain)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: selectedElement)
            .tint(currentColor)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        .background {
            currentColor
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
        .animation(.smooth(duration: 2.0), value: backgroundHue)
    }
    
}

//MARK: - Artist card view

struct ArtistCard: View {
    
    var image: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Group {
            if image != "" {
                Image(image)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
            }
            else {
                Color.yellow
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
    }
}

//MARK: - Arc Shape

struct RoundCornerArc: Shape {
    
    //Parameters
    var radius: CGFloat = 120
    
    //Path
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        
        return Path { path in
            
            // Define points
            let start = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY) // Bottom-left corner
            let end = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY)    // Top-right corner
            
            // Start drawing
            path.move(to: start) // Start at bottom-left
            path.addArc(tangent1End: .zero, tangent2End: end, radius: radius) //Add arc to top-right
            path.addLine(to: .zero) // Draw vertical line to top-left
            path.closeSubpath() //Close the path to bottom-left point
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - View extension

extension View {
    
    func roundCorners<Corners: View>(_ mode: RoundCorner.MaskMode = .mask,
        @ViewBuilder corners: () -> Corners
    ) -> some View {
        self.modifier(RoundCornersViewModifier(mode: mode, corners: corners))
    }
}

//MARK: - View modifier

struct RoundCornersViewModifier<Corners: View>: ViewModifier {
    
    //Parameters
    var mode: RoundCorner.MaskMode = .mask
    @ViewBuilder let corners: Corners
    
    //ViewModifier body
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background {
                if mode == .fill {
                    Rectangle()
                        .overlay {
                            corners
                        }
                        .compositingGroup()
                        .blendMode(.destinationOut)
                }
            }
            .overlay {
                if mode == .mask {
                    corners
                }
            }
    }
    
    
}

//MARK: - RoundCorner view

struct RoundCorner: View {
    
    public enum MaskMode {
        case mask, fill
    }
    
    //Parameters
    var radius: CGFloat = 20
    var alignment: Alignment = .topLeading
    var orientation: Alignment = .topLeading
    var position: MaskPosition = .inside
    var flip: Edge = .leading
    var blend: Bool = true
    var fill: Color?
    var preview: Bool = false
    var previewColor: Color = .black
    var mode: String = ""
    
    //Computed properties
    private var rotation: Angle {
        switch orientation {
            case .topLeading: return .degrees(0)
            case .bottomTrailing: return .degrees(-180)
            case .topTrailing: return .degrees(90)
            case .bottomLeading: return .degrees(-90)
            default: return .degrees(0)
        }
    }
    
    private var offsetX: CGFloat {
        switch position {
            case .inside:
                switch flip {
                    case .top:
                        return 0
                    case .bottom:
                        return 0
                    case .trailing:
                        return 0
                    case .leading:
                        return 0
                }
            case .outside:
                switch flip {
                    case .top:
                        return 0
                    case .bottom:
                        return 0
                    case .trailing:
                        return radius
                    case .leading:
                        return -radius
                }
        }
    }
    
    private var offsetY: CGFloat {
        switch position {
            case .inside:
                switch flip {
                    case .top:
                        return 0
                    case .bottom:
                        return 0
                    case .trailing:
                        return 0
                    case .leading:
                        return 0
                }
            case .outside:
                switch flip {
                    case .top:
                        return -radius
                    case .bottom:
                        return radius
                    case .trailing:
                        return 0
                    case .leading:
                        return 0
                }
        }
    }
    
    //View body
    var body: some View {
        Color.clear
            .overlay(alignment: alignment) {
                RoundCornerArc(radius: radius)
                    .fill(preview ? previewColor : fill ?? .black)
                    .frame(width: radius, height: radius)
                    .rotationEffect(rotation)
                    .blendMode(preview ? .normal : blend ? .destinationOut : .normal)
                    .border(preview ? previewColor : .clear)
                    .offset(x: offsetX, y: offsetY)
            }
    }
}


//MARK: - MaskPosition enum for view modifier

enum MaskPosition {
    case inside, outside
}

//MARK: - Helper enum for form controls

enum ElementType {
    case rect, circle
}

//Test view for alternate preview
struct RoundCornerTest: View {
    
    //State values
    @State private var debug: Bool = false
    
    //Computed properties
    private var preview: Bool {
        !debug
    }
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            //Example 1 - Simple
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.yellow)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .roundCorners {
                    
                    //Round corner - Inside - Top left
                    RoundCorner(radius: 40, alignment: .topLeading, orientation: .topLeading, position: .inside, flip: .top, blend: true, preview: preview, previewColor: .black)
                        
                    //Round corner - Outside - Top right
                    RoundCorner(radius: 80, alignment: .topTrailing, orientation: .bottomTrailing, position: .outside, flip: .top, blend: false, fill:  .yellow,  preview: preview, previewColor: .pink)
                }
                .compositingGroup()
                .padding(.bottom, 50)

            
            //Example 2 - Advanced
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .fill(.black)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                    
                    //Place rectangle at the bottom
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.white)
                        .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                        .roundCorners {
                            
                            //Round corners - Top left
                            RoundCorner(radius: 40, alignment: .topLeading, orientation: .bottomLeading, position: .outside, flip: .top, preview: preview, previewColor: .yellow)
                            RoundCorner(radius: 30, alignment: .topLeading, orientation: .topTrailing, position: .outside, flip: .leading, preview: preview, previewColor: .red)
                            RoundCorner(radius: 20, alignment: .topLeading, orientation: .topLeading, position: .inside, preview: preview, previewColor: .orange)
                            
                            // Round corners - Top right
                            RoundCorner(radius: 40, alignment: .topTrailing, orientation: .bottomTrailing, position: .outside, flip: .top, preview: preview, previewColor: .pink)
                            RoundCorner(radius: 30, alignment: .topTrailing, orientation: .topLeading, position: .outside, flip: .trailing, preview: preview, previewColor: .indigo)
                            RoundCorner(radius: 20, alignment: .topTrailing, orientation: .topTrailing, position: .inside, preview: preview, previewColor: .orange)
                            
                            //Round corners - Bottom left
                            RoundCorner(radius: 40, alignment: .bottomLeading, orientation: .bottomTrailing, position: .outside, flip: .leading, preview: preview, previewColor: .green)
                            
                            //Round corners - Bottom right
                            RoundCorner(radius: 40, alignment: .bottomTrailing, orientation: .bottomLeading, position: .outside, flip: .trailing, preview: preview, previewColor: .teal)
                        }
                        .animation(.default, value: preview)
                }
                .compositingGroup()
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            
            
            //Preview toggle
            Toggle("Preview", isOn: $debug)
                .fixedSize()
                .padding()
                .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
        }
    }
}

#Preview("CustomArtistCard Demo") {
    CustomArtistCard()
}

#Preview("RoundCorner Test") {
    RoundCornerTest()
}

#Preview("Arc Shape") {
    RoundCornerArc()
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
        .foregroundStyle(.yellow)
}

#Preview("Artist Card") {
    ArtistCard() // or ArtistCard(image: "") <- Specify your named image from Assets here
}


Note: In case I may have missed some minor details above and you're having issues making it work, just post a comment about it.

Yes, this is another way to do it. In fact I tried it this way too, but using UnevenRoundedRectangle for 6 of the 8 rounded corners. The two inner corners require a filler shape, as you are also using. I created a custom shape for the filler. But then I reckoned that if a custom shape is going to be used anyway, it might as well be for the complete card.

Got it, thanks for looking it over.
